# Как проверить наличие кнопки по тэгу в массиве?

Tags: ios, swift

Есть несколько кнопок(с тэгами), при нажатии которых, выполняется функция добавления самой кнопки в массив. Как сделать проверку на наличие кнопки по тэгу в массиве? Пытался через arr.contrainsObject, но не получается. Подскажите куда копать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте в цикле перебрать массив.

```
for (index, item) in array.enumerate() {
     let button = item as! UIButton
     if button.tag == yourTag {
       // значит вы нашли нужную кнопку
     }
}
```

Comment: работает, большое спасибо! еще 1 тупой вопрос, если знаете - ответьте пожалуйста. почему не работает запись if button.tag == x && button.tag == y? а с || работает.

Comment: Так как `&&` означает логическое И, а `||` означает логическое ИЛИ. Что значит if button.tag == x И button.tag == y, а ваша кнопка не может именть сразу два тэга. Ваша запись означает тэг кнопки равен = 2 и тэг кнопки равен 3. Такого не может быть, а с или работает так как тэг кнопки равен или 2 или 3. Одно из двух. Если Вы путаетесь в логических операциях, стоит их повторить. Но я для себя запомнил так - И это умножение ИЛИ сложение, грубо говоря 1*1 = 1, 1*0 = 0, т.е. если одно из условий 0 значит результат 0, а при сложении 1 + 0 = 1; Если хоть одно из слагаемых равно 1, то и результат 1.

Comment: @Yurjke Если ответ Вам помог, отметьте его как правильный =)